# How to know if I've done the necessary corrections to my data so that the regression is valid?

Tags: econometrics, stata

Obviously the data can't be changed to fit a regression, it should be (kind of) the other way around.

But, sometimes the data has stuff going on that needs correction. For example, I got raw data from the Law Enforcement Management And Administrative Statistics 2007 survey. I did a linear multiple regression on it using Stata, and then analyzed the residuals and found heteroskedasticity. So I corrected for it by using the `, robust` option in my regression code.

Sometimes the data have other problems like data points that are very influential. And sometimes the data doesn't have a very linear relation, more of a curvy one. And I don't know a lot about regression, but I think there are other possible problems with data. Maybe partially filled surveys or falsified information.

Anyway, how do I know that the data itself was good, and that instead (if there were a problem) the problem was in the regression?

I was using this page to try to guide myself through the process http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/reg/chapter2/statareg2.htm
but I don't know if that's everything I have to check for.

Comment: As an alternative to using robust standard errors, you could try running a GLS or WLS (generalized least squares and weighted LS) rather than use an inefficient OLS estimator.

Comment: Obviously you cannot change the data, so what you asking is not very clear? In some cases, you can truncate the data by excluding some outliers, you can also use the log of variables in some other cases, but I think that pretty much all you can do without being accused of data-mining. Regarding the quality of the regression, it really depends on each case. There are dozens of econometric textbooks that explain all refinements you can do to OLS. It also depends on what you're doing : time-series, cross-section, panel, etc. If you provide a specific example, someone might be able to help you.